# Iterate Array Inside of Array Angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, select, angular-forms

How can i iterate these arrays inside of arrays in select option in angular 4? I have this codes below. The problem that it produces several select option instead of a single select option. I want to iterate the acct_type_name only. How can i solve this? Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

> TS

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let account of accounts">
                      <select type="text" class="form-control">
                        <option *ngFor="let accountss of account.account_types">{{ accountss.acct_type_name }}</option>
                      </select>
                    </ng-container>
```

> JSON

```
[
  {
    "account_type_cla_id": 1,
    "account_type_cla_name": "Assets",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "account_types": [
      {
        "acc_type_id": 1,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Other Asset",
        "acct_type_description": "Other Asset",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 2,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Other Current Asset",
        "acct_type_description": "Other Current Asset",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 3,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Cash",
        "acct_type_description": "Cash",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 4,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Bank",
        "acct_type_description": "Bank",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 5,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Fixed Asset",
        "acct_type_description": "Fixed Asset",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 6,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 1,
        "acct_type_name": "Stock",
        "acct_type_description": "Stock",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "account_type_cla_id": 2,
    "account_type_cla_name": "Liability",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "account_types": [
      {
        "acc_type_id": 7,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 2,
        "acct_type_name": "Other Current Liability",
        "acct_type_description": "Other Current Liability",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 8,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 2,
        "acct_type_name": "Credit Card",
        "acct_type_description": "Credit Card",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "acc_type_id": 9,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 2,
        "acct_type_name": "Long Term Liability",
        "acct_type_description": "Long Term Liability",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "account_type_cla_id": 3,
    "account_type_cla_name": "Equity",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "account_types": [
      {
        "acc_type_id": 10,
        "acc_type_cla_id": 3,
        "acct_type_name": "Equity",
        "acct_type_description": "Equity",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Do you want a single dropdown to show all the options?
Currently it shows correctly the way you template it.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam. Yes only one single dropdown

Comment: All `acct_type_name` from the three different account?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam. Yes i want to iterate acct_type_name from three different accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use nested ngFor in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622949/how-to-use-nested-ngfor-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Template file**

```
<ng-container>
    <select type="text" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let acct_type_name of getAcctTypeName()">{{ acct_type_name }}</option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

If your sample data is in accounts property add this in **typescript file**

```
getAcctTypeName(){
  let accountTypeName:string[]=[];
  this.accounts.forEach(account=>{
    account.account_types.forEach(accountTypeItem=>{
      accountTypeName.push(accountTypeItem.acct_type_name); 
    });
  });
  return accountTypeName;
}
```

Comment: its better to close the duplicate questions rather than posting answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take `ng-container` inside of `select` tag

```
<select type="text" class="form-control">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let account of accounts">
        <option *ngFor="let accountss of account.account_types">{{ accountss.acct_type_name }}</option>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

Comment: its better to close the duplicate questions rather than posting answer

Comment: @faceturn, usser already knows `how to Iterate Array Inside of Array Angular 4` , question tag line is wrong , and OP is not clear about the logic , as you can see in the code he has already implemented it , but dont know where to.

Comment: @VivekDoshi. Thanks. Did you solve my pagination problem yesterday?

Comment: I need some working example for that, will you please create one on https://stackblitz.com ?