# Error iterating Array with ngFor: "Identifier 'xxx' is not defined"

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am trying to iterate an array on my data model and I get the following error in VSCode:

> Identifier 'familiares' is not defined. '{ nombre: string;
> edadTitular: number; primaTitular: number; familiares: { vinculo:
> string; edad: number; prima: number; }[]; }[]' does not contain such a
> memberng

In console it does not show any error. That could be happening?

**component.ts**

```
primas = [
    {
      nombre: 'name1',
      edadTitular: 36,
      primaTitular: 9010,
      familiares: ['fam1', 'fam2']
    },
    {
      nombre: 'name 2',
      edadTitular: 36,
      primaTitular: 9698,
      familiares: [ 'fam3', 'fam4' ]
    },
  ];
```

**components.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let familiar of primas.familiares">
   {{familiar}}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"primas" is an array, meaning you have to select the index for that array. You have two options here. The first being you can choose an index if you have a particular object in "primas" you want to access:

```
<div *ngFor="let familiar of primas[0].familiares">
```

The second being you can nest your current **ngFor* in another **ngFor*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let prima of primas">
    <!--notice that the below code accesses prima (singular) from above-->
    <div *ngFor="let familiar of prima.familiares">
       {{familiar}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Great confusion of mine. I was actually looking for the second solution, I was confusing `prima` with `primas` Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

The primas variable is its self an array. You have to first index which object inside primas you mean. Then you can iterate inside that object's familiares list.

You better look into the following link
[Iterate Array Inside of Array Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273700/iterate-array-inside-of-array-angular-4)